# Explosion in bomberman doesn't work properly sometimes

Tags: c#, for-loop, monogame

I'm working on a bomberman for fun, but there is a problem with the loop for the explosions.
Sometimes it works correctly and stops when it destroys a block, but sometimes it keeps on going until the max explosion size has been reached.

To help visualize:

```
Explosion size = 5
layout:                      Bomb     |Empty    |Breakable|Breakable|Breakable|Breakable
becomes sometimes (correct): Explosion|Explosion|Explosion|Breakable|Breakable|Breakable
and sometimes (incorrect):   Explosion|Explosion|Explosion|Explosion|Explosion|Breakable
```

It's like the breaks sometimes get ignored in the code.
There is no pattern and the code does recognize all blocks correctly

This is the code for control to the right side of the explosion.

```
for (int j = 1; j < player.ExplosionSize; j++)
{
    breakPointRight = j + 1;
    if ((int)map.ArrayMap.GetValue((int)bombs[i].Grid.X + j, (int)bombs[i].Grid.Y) == (int)Constants.ENUMMAP.unbreakable)
        break;
    else if ((int)map.ArrayMap.GetValue((int)bombs[i].Grid.X + j, (int)bombs[i].Grid.Y) == (int)Constants.ENUMMAP.free)
        map.ArrayMap.SetValue(Constants.ENUMMAP.explosion, (int)bombs[i].Grid.X + j, (int)bombs[i].Grid.Y);
    else if ((int)map.ArrayMap.GetValue((int)bombs[i].Grid.X + j, (int)bombs[i].Grid.Y) == (int)Constants.ENUMMAP.breakable)
    {
        CalculateChanceforPickup((int)bombs[i].Grid.X + j, (int)bombs[i].Grid.Y);
        break;
    }
    //check if block is a pickup
    else if ((int)map.ArrayMap.GetValue((int)bombs[i].Grid.X + j, (int)bombs[i].Grid.Y) > (int)Constants.ENUMMAP.free)
    {
        map.ArrayMap.SetValue(Constants.ENUMMAP.explosion, (int)bombs[i].Grid.X + j, (int)bombs[i].Grid.Y );
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: just looking at the code, there's no final `else`, which means if none of the conditions are met it will loop until `ExplosionSize`.

Comment: Now that you've said it. 
Normally there shouldn't be an 'else' necessary (all situations are accounted for), but i'll add one just to be sure.

Comment: There can be a difference between what you expect the code does and what the program actually does. It's recommended to debug the moment it explodes (by placing a breakpoint) so you can see step for step what the program actually does.